# How can I select items that don't have a particular column value?

Tags: mysql

My data looks like this:

```
group_id | meta_key | meta_value
----------------------------------------
    33   | has_foo  | definitely_has_foo
    33   | is_bar   | might_be_bar
    33   | a_key    | a_value
    65   | has_foo  | probably
    86   | something| something_else
```

I want to select all `group_id`s that *don't* have a `meta_key` called `has_foo`, which in this case would be `86`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select group_id
from your_table
group by group_id
having sum(meta_key = 'has_foo') = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT group_id 
FROM T
WHERE group_id NOT IN (SELECT group_id FROM T WHERE meta_key = 'has_foo')
```